# Can I use ad in Android apps without creating AdSense account?

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

Sometime Google denies AdSense account that user create, that's why I wonder about it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, you should have an ad unit id to request an ad. Since without logging in to the dashboard, you cannot get an ad unit id.

PS: You can use other users ad unit id, but I don't know weather it is allowed or not.